# Is that possible to create negative bar chart using GraphView library in Android?

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, android-graphview

I'm looking library that allow to build bar charts with negative values like on picture below.
I tried already AndroidPlot(impossible to achieve this on version 0.6.0) and GraphView(look like impossible, actually i get same result as in AndroidPlot)
Greatly appreciate any help.

[image: Bar chart with negative values]

Comment: I already found an answer for my question:
It is impossible via `GraphView` library but possible using `AChartEngine` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible via `GraphView` library but possible using `AChartEngine` library.